# titanium-mobile scheduled task on iphone/android?

Tags: iphone, android, scheduled-tasks, titanium

I'd like to and app every 6 hours or every 12 hours to get updates from a webserver

I know this is possible in native android using the alarmmanager.
Can I do this for both android and iphone in titanium-mobile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there a several possibilities to implement that feature. you can google for a push service. another way is to calculate the interval. i would save the installation date and check for the difference moduls 6.

```
need_to_update = function(installed_time){
  /* current time */
  var current_date = new Date();
  var current_hour = current_date.getHours();

  /* check diff */
  var installed_hour = installed_time.getHours();
  var diff = Math.abs(installed_hour-current_hour);

  /* check interval - here 6 hour interval*/
  var mod = diff % 6;

  /* return result */
  return mod == 0;
}
```

example: 
installed_hour = 18; 
current_hour = 20;
diff = 2;
mod = 2;
returns false;

example two:
installed_hour = 4;
current_hour = 16;
diff = 12;
mod = 0;
returns true;

Comment: as far as I know push notifications are only available for android from 2.3 so that's not an option... I guess I'll have to make a service run in the background then?